# Find last instance of some text in a range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to pull the row number of whichever row contains the LAST instance of a cell that contains some text.

For example in the table below, I want to search the range A1:A20 for any cell containing *SLOT:*

Any ideas how I could get it to return, in this instance, row 15 (the last row containing *SLOT:*)
I'm using MATCH/INDIRECT so far but only getting the first instance (returns row 4).

Many thinks in advance!

Adam

(question updated with text version of table)

```
    |            A
--------------------------------
 1  |  NETIN:NETI.#DP_COIL_01;
 2  |  SLOT:15;
 3  |  CHAN:1600;
 4  |  BITIN:NETI.#XI90109(0);
 5  |  BITIN:NETI.#XI90110(2);
 6  |  /;
 7  |  DEF:NETIN:NETI.#ADAM_TEST;
 8  |  SLOT:15;
 9  |  CHAN:1301;
10  |  BITIN:NETI.#ZS100(0);
11  |  BITIN:NETI.#ZS101(1);
12  |  BITIN:NETI.#ZS102(2);
13  |  /;
14  |  DEF:NETIN:NETI.#DP_DISCRETE_01;
15  |  SLOT:15;
16  |  CHAN:1601;
17  |  BITIN:NETI.#XA90111(5);
18  |  BITIN:NETI.#XA90112(6);
19  |  BITIN:NETI.#XA90113(7);
20  |  /;
```

Comment: For future questions, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=For%20larger%20code%20snippets%2C%20you,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the row number:

```
=XLOOKUP("*slot*",$A$1:$A$20,SEQUENCE(20),,2,-1)
```

If you want the contents of the cell:

```
=XLOOKUP("*slot*",$A$1:$A$20,$A$1:$A$20,,2,-1)
```

Examine ***HELP*** for `XLOOKUP` to better understand the implications of the optional arguments.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

> =MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("slot", A1:A20)), ROW(A1:A20),0))